# Get the documents having the max_score

Tags: elasticsearch

When I make query, I am getting many documents with varying _score value. Documents are sorted desc by _score.

I need to get all the documents which are having the highest score.

Lets say, I have documents d1,d2...d10.

As a result of my query, the _score for each document is like below.

- d7 - 17.112
- d3 - 17.112
- d2 - 17.112
- d1 - 16.9
- d9 - 16.9
- d9 - 16.2
- d10 - 15.7
- d6 - 15.7
- d5 - 14
- d8 - 14

I just want to get d7, d3, d2 as these three documents are having the highest score.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You specify the number of documents with the `size` parameter. You could hit the `_search` endpoint with the following:

```
GET /index-name/index-type/_search
{
    "size" : 3,
    "query" : {
      "term" : { "field" : "match-text" }
    }
}
```